# MySQL casting string to varbinary

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update a table, but the field I want to update (appdata) is varbinary, so this doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions`
SET `appdata`='ext110,1'
WHERE `context`=0x696E636F6D696E67
  AND`exten`=0x3031363134363437333839
  AND`priority`='51';
```

I guess I need to convert the value to binary first, but i'm still getting an error

```
UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions`
SET `appdata`=BINARY('ext110,1')
WHERE `context`=0x696E636F6D696E67
  AND`exten`=0x3031363134363437333839
  AND`priority`='51';
```

> ERROR 0: 0: MySQL_Prepared_Statement::setBlob: invalid 'parameterIndex' SQL Statement: UPDATE `asterisk`.`extensions` SET `appdata`=BINARY('ext110,1') WHERE `context`=0x696E636F6D696E67 and`exten`=0x3031363134363437333839 and`priority`='51'

Comment: MYSQL workbench version?

Comment: version 6.3.7 build 1199 CE

Comment: Can you try `SET appdata=CAST('ext110,1' as binary)` ?

Comment: Same error - ERROR 0: 0: MySQL_Prepared_Statement::setBlob: invalid 'parameterIndex'

Comment: Can you share create table script? I am unable to reproduce this at my end.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `extensions` (
  `context` varbinary(50) NOT NULL,
  `exten` varbinary(50) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app` varbinary(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appdata` varbinary(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type` varbinary(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`context`,`exten`,`priority`),
  KEY `by_unit` (`unit`),
  KEY `by_relation` (`relation_type`,`relation_id`)
)